# Migration from parse to azure not working for mobile app

Tags: ios, azure, parse-platform, database-migration

i have migrated my iOS app parse DB to Azure, but had not finalised it yet.
I have changed end point to azure URL and its almost fine i mean i can login with my previous accounts.
But when i am querying anything to fetch or update data it giving me errors in response like:

[Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.13.0)
[Error]: Response status code was unacceptable: 404
[Error]: This user is not allowed to access non-existent class: user (Code: 119, Version: 1.13.0)

Can anybody help me here that, will it be possible to update or fetch data to azure only after i finalize at parse migration or still there is something which i need to update from my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from azure document.
I was getting error for fetching parse's PFFile object, and for that i need to add file key in azure settings. the value for the key can be find from azure settings.
[image of azure settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRRvC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. You just need to go to the parse dashboard and create the class

Comment: what type of class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in the ParseDashboard which will fix the problem. I was not able to open parse dashboard in browser (Only allowed remote https connection). I had to start it locally and finally was able to open the dashboard. Then i created the class there and it fixed my problem.
To launch the dashboard locally run the following commands

`npm install -g parse-dashboard` 
and 
`parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "https://example.com/parse" --appName optionalName`

[image]